# Derivations of $K[X]/I$ for $I$ an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

On a book I’m studying I found this statement: given $I$ an ideal of $K[X]$ (polynomial ring in n variables) then:

$ Der_k(A) = \{ D \in Der_k(K[X]) \; | \; D(I) \subset I \} $

Where $A = K[X]/I$. I feel this is not true: given the fact that $K[X]$  has a free module of kahler differentials I can lift every derivation of $A$, but there is no reason for which this lifting should be unique. Am I right? If not please give the proof of the statement. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you're right, as far as I can tell.